# how to automaticly show the latest time's point's tooltip in the highchart, as if the mouse on it?

Tags: highcharts

I know that when my mouse is on the chart, it will show the points and tooltips as below:
[image]

I want:

1. Auto show the last points' tooltips, without mouse on it.
2. when exporting, also show the last tooltips, as in the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/dodouwang/Lh53fyu7/2/

```
    // Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  exporting: {
     useHTML: true
  },
  chart: {
    type: 'spline'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Mountain house indoor temperatures'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Split tooltips in Highcharts makes it easier to read overlapping line series'
  },

  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: '°C',
    split: true,
    distance: 30,
    padding: 5
  },

  xAxis: {
    crosshair: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Temperatur'
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      lineWidth: 1.5,
      marker: {
        radius: 2
      }
    }
  },

  data: {
    columns: [
      ["Time", 1451616120000, 1451865660000, 1451952060000, 1452038400000, 1452124800000, 1452211200000, 1452297600000, 1452384000000, 1452470400000, 1452556800000, 1452643200000, 1452729600000, 1452816000000, 1452902400000, 1452988800000, 1453075200000, 1453161600000, 1453248000000, 1453334400000, 1453420800000, 1453507200000, 1453593600000, 1453680000000, 1453766400000, 1453852800000, 1453939200000, 1454025600000],
      ["Kitchen", 5, 4, 5, 9, 6, 15, 19, 14, 6, 5, 6, 6, 15, 18, 15, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 16, 10, 6, 6, 6],
      ["Living room", 9, 10, 16, 13, 6, 20, 24, 16, 7, 7, 6, 6, 20, 23, 18, 9, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 21, 20, 16, 6, 6, 6],
      ["Hall", 7, 7, 13, 12, 5, 17, 22, 14, 4, 5, 5, 6, 18, 21, 17, 9, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 18, 20, 14, 5, 5, 5],
      ["Bathroom", 7, 7, 13, 12, 5, 17, 22, 14, 4, 5, 5, 6, 18, 21, 17, 9, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 18, 20, 14, 5, 5, 5],
      ["Bedroom 1", 6, 19, 19, 10, 5, 15, 21, 14, 6, 6, 5, 5, 17, 21, 16, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 17, 18, 13, 5, 5, 5],
      ["Bedroom 2", 7, 19, 19, 9, 5, 11, 19, 15, 6, 5, 6, 6, 16, 19, 17, 8, 9, 6, 5, 6, 5, 17, 19, 14, 6, 6, 6],
      ["Shed", 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, null, null, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
    ]
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achived by using `tooltip.refresh` method:

```
function(chart) {
  let points = [];
  chart.series.forEach(series => {
    points.push(series.points[series.points.length - 1])
  })

  chart.tooltip.refresh(points)
})
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cqp96b0d/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Tooltip#refresh

---

**EDIT:**

Add this function in the `exporting.chartOptions` on `chart.load` event as well - this allows to show tooltips automatically during exporting.

```
  exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        events: {
          load() {
            let points = [];
            this.series.forEach(series => {
              points.push(series.points[series.points.length - 1])
            })

            this.tooltip.refresh(points)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/24tjysnd/

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to export it , the tooltip dispeared. How can I keep it when exporting?

Comment: @Dodou Wang - Apologize, I missed your second requirement - you will find the solution in the edited answer.